# How to configure openid-connect with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, openid-connect

```
  kubectl config set-credentials USER_NAME \
   --auth-provider=oidc \
   --auth-provider-arg=idp-issuer-url=( issuer url ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=client-id=( your client id ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=client-secret=( your client secret ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=refresh-token=( your refresh token ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=idp-certificate-authority=( path to your ca certificate ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=id-token=( your id_token ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=extra-scopes=( comma separated list of scopes to add to "openid email profile", optional )
```

Is this sufficient to configure openid-connect with kubernetes?
Can someone tell me what are the value for

**1. issuer url
 2. refresh token
 3. path to ca certificate
 4. extra-scopes
 5. id-token**

Also just to confirm, i would like to know if **client secret and client ID are the same as the google credentials created**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the k8s-oidc-helper tool. To this pass the google credential (JSON file). This will then open the browser to provide a secret code.
Copy and paste it to get the required OIDC paramters.